# Migrating to Fasthosts server - Locating a scripting path in order to update it

Tags: asp.net, migration, server

My brother's website was previously on the Streamline servers, however they recently got taken over by Fasthosts and although the front end of his still site works fine he cannot access the CMS. I've looked into this and noticed that on trying to get into the CMS an ASP 131 error message appeared highlighting disallowed parent paths.

In a conversation with the Fasthosts tech support this morning they confirmed that they do actually enable parent paths by default and that all I need to do is update the scripting path with the new one.

Since I'm not the developer of his site I didn't know, off-hand, where the scripting path would reside. I've looked through all of the files but cannot see it anywhere. Does anyone with experience in ASP have any idea where this is likely to be?

Thanks.